# Seeking to understand the use of the number 7 in the book of Daniel

Tags: numbers, daniel, symbolism

I realize that the number 7 is used symbolically throughout the bible, prophets and writings. I noticed that the use of sevens seems to occur frequently in the book of Daniel. A few examples

- number of dignitaries invited to the inauguration of the statue in chapter 3
- Number of musical instruments in the same
- the passage of time that king Nebuchadnezzar was punished with madness (chapter 4)
- the enigmatic vision in 9:24-27

I would like to understand, holistically, if there is a reason this number comes up so frequently in this book.

Comment: [Babylonians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_captivity) were master [astronomers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_astronomy), familiar with the [seven classical planets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_planet), rotating around the earth in an opposite direction to that of [the rest of its stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_stars), and the time-span of seven days and nine hours between consecutive moon-phases; and with this being the first integer not to divide the number [sixty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal), their common base of numeration.

Answer (score 1):

- 7 is a holy number in Judiasm that repreents completeness
- Daniel who was an Israilite wrote this book when he was in captivity in Babylon
- There are several places in Tanakh where 7 is called out.

1. The menorah in the Temple had seven lamps
2. Acts of atonement and purification were accompanied by a sevenfold sprinkling
3. Number of days of Sukkot
4. Number of days of Pesach
5. Seven are the days of the week
6. The Seven Laws of Noah

Answer (score 0):

The number "seven" appears
46 times in Genesis,
31 times in Revelation,
12 times in Judges, and only
6 times in the book of Daniel.

> I would like to understand, holistically, if there is a reason this number comes up so frequently in this book.

I do not want to underestimate the significance of "seven" in the book of Daniel but the fact remains that it does not appear that frequently in this book compared with other books.